# How to programmatically check if site permissions are modified?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, site, last-modified-date

I am working on building a report where I need the list of all the sites whose permissions got updated in the last 7 days or any specific period and we have some business logic to perform once we have the sites.

I am using CSOM as we are using SharePoint Online. We need to track classic and modern sites.

Do we have any specific Web level property which we can use to track the above change?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you must have to use CSOM?

In my opinion, I suggest you use audit log search.

Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Security -> Search -> Audit log search

After getting the search results, you could export the report.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is manual effort and we are planning to automate our solution